# Plucking ranged percentages via regex

Tags: java, regex, java-8

I am accepting a string from user input and trying to determine if it matches a regex. If it does I need to pluck certain matched groups out of the input and process them.

The valid string must be of the form:

- 1 number that can consist of integers or floating points (decimal point)
- followed by a hyphen ("`-`")
- followed by another number (same as the first)
- **optionally** ended with a percent sign ("`%`")

Examples of valid string inputs:

- "6-9"
- "6.5-9"
- "6-9.24"
- "6-9%"
- "6.5-9%"
- "6.24-9.23%"

My best attempt:

```
String numRange = getFromUser();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2})[%]*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(numRange);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    String lowRangeVal = matcher.group(1);
    String highRangeVal = matcher.group(2);

    // continue processing here
}
```

Does not work. Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your pattern to fit your requirement as following.

```
([0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,2})*)-([0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,2})*)[%]*
```

I only added optional (`*`) to the decimal place and second number part.
And I assumed that number before or after the decimal place is limited to length 1 to 2, although you did not say so.

https://regex101.com/r/5fpUB2/1

Comment: An optional part is defined by using `?`. Your `*` means “any number of occurrences”, in other words, allows more than one.

Comment: @Holger You right. `?` (zero or once) is more reasonable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)-(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)%*");
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/eJfX7y/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %*                       '%' (0 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
```